# prove C is a proper subset of ℕ. Then prove ℕ is infinite.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory

Please, can you help me to do this?

> Let $C =\{n + n \;|\; n\in \mathbb{N} \}$, and define $f:\mathbb{N}\to C$ by $f(n) = n + n$.  First prove $C$ is a proper subset of $\mathbb{N}$. Then prove $\mathbb{N}$ is infinite.

We have a definition that says a set $A$ is infinite iff there exists a set $C \subsetneq A$ such that $C \sim A$.

Comment: I thought this was the definition for an infinite set -- what is the definition of infinite that you are using and need to prove this is equivalent to?

Comment: indeed I don't know. that is what we have only

Comment: $f$ is not 1-1 but onto.

Comment: Well it seems like you are being hard on yourself then: if you don't know what you are trying to prove, then it is going to be difficult to prove it. Anyway, hopefully this helps: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Infinite_Set

Comment: @hardmath yes, it is.

Comment: The problem has two parts. Which of them do you have trouble with?

Comment: I edited your Question to use math expressions in $\LaTeX$ as the site supports via [MathJax](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).  I tried to be kind of faithful, but notice the "similarity" symbol $\sim$ stands in need of definition for some Readers (equicardinality), and the I've made a slight correction to your working definition of "infinite" (more properly Dedekind infinite) to emphasize $C$ is a proper subset of $A$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm both

Comment: @hardmath thank you all

Comment: @haron: Do you know what "$C$ is a proper subset of $\mathbb N$" _means_? Do you understand what the elements of $C$ are?

Comment: @HenningMakholm  C is a proper subset of N , all elements of C are in N but N contains at least one element that is not in C

Comment: @haron: And is that true for the $C$ defined in the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$C$ is a subset of $\mathbb{N}$ since $n+n \in \mathbb{N}$ for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

$C$ is a proper subset of $\mathbb{N}$ since, for example, $1 \not \in C$.

But $C$ and $\mathbb{N}$ have the same cardinality since $f$ is one-to-one and onto. Hence they are both infinite sets.

I brushed over the details here. They are up to you to fill in.

Comment: Thank you, but how we can prove 1 ∉ ℂ?

Comment: $1 \in C \implies \exists n \in \mathbb{N} \mid f(n) = n + n = 1$. Hence $n = \frac{1}{2}$, but $\frac{1}{2} \not \in \mathbb{N}$.